# using jQuery data() vs. property on dom node object

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Why would I want to use jQuery's `data(...)` or `$.data(...)` instead of just setting a property on a DOM node object, in a "static dom" context where I see no risk of memory leaks?

For example, why this:

```
$('#my-id').data('mykey', 42);
// ...
var retrived_value = $('#my-id').data('mykey');
```

...instead of;

```
var myel = document.getElementById('my-id');
myel._mykey = 42;
// ...
var myel_second_reference = document.getElementById('my-id');
var retrieved_value = myel_second_reference._mykey;
```

I know the jQuery docs say that this:

> allows us to attach data of any type to DOM elements in a way that is
>   safe from circular references and therefore free from memory leaks

...but would any such leaks occur in a simple usage scenario where no DOM nodes get created or removed? Or, another way to put it, can I safely use the *"naive method"* in a *"static DOM"* scenarion?

Comment: Avoiding circular references is a good strategy, but it's not the sole source of memory leaks, nor are DOM properties so the statement is somewhat misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Memory leaks shouldn't be your primary concern. You've quoted the jquery docs (own emphasis):

> allows us to attach data **of any type** to DOM elements

The naive method restricts you to string values. while automatic casting might suffice for basic data types, consider attaching a full-fledged javascript object.

Comment: "The naive method restricts you to string values", which method is that?

Comment: @RobG The naive method here is what the op refers to at the beginning of his question: 'setting a property on a DOM node object'.

Comment: @collapsar not doesn't, at least in the browsers I've tested in. For example, I can just use the console and on the dom of this page do:

`var x = $('ul').first()[0];
x._prop = {name: 23, fun: function () { console.log('foo!!!'); }};
var x_again = $('ul').first()[0];
x_again._prop.fun();` and see the logged `foo!!!` (I used x_again to just prove there was no other "magic" way the prop was being attached). As far as I see DOM objects behave as regular Javascript objects concerning their not-already-existing properties...

Comment: @RobG Like just doing `var el = document.getElementById('my-id')` (or the equivalent `var el = $('#myid')[0]`) and then `el._my_prop = 'my val'` and later on (using the same `el` or another reference to the same DOM node) doing `var retrieved_value = el2._my_prop`. But as far as I see, one can very well use any object instead of a simple string...

Comment: @RobG I realized my code sample from the question was a bit confusing, so I edited the code in my question to make it more clearer what I mean.

Comment: @NeuronQ thanks for the info, I stand corrected. Still the jquery `data` method seems to come with a benefit when cloning a node: jquery takes account of the associated data while DOM's `cloneNode` doesn't.